# Sitecore Call Templates with Widgets

Tags: templates, sitecore

When I insert template, can the template call sublayouts automatically, so that I can avoid to add sublayouts manually?

Suppose:
I have a.ascx, b.ascx, c.ascx as widgets
I have ttt.ascx as template.

When I create a page with ttt template, it leads a, b and c widgets with placeholder key names in presentation.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean "ttt.ascx as template"? Do you mean a Sitecore data template? If so, that would not be a physical file. Can you be more clear in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the presentation details on the Standard Values of the template. Any item that you create with that template will use these default values.

[Bind Presentation Elements to Sitecore Templates](https://www.cmssource.co.uk/blog/2012/June/basic-sitecore-development-tutorial-part-5-bind-presentation-elements-to-sitecore-templates)

If you make any changes to the Item once it is created then the differences are stored as [Layout Deltas](https://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2010/10/Layout-Deltas-What-Ifs.aspx).

You need to make sure you have added the Standard Values for the template: 
[Standard Values in Sitecore](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/Developers/Articles/2010/08/Standard-values-in-sitecore.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, jammykam. I have one quick question. Is it possible Sitecore to choose templates automatically by retrieving deep level of the item's path. Suppose that there are two templates, Toy (main) and sub-Toy (sub). When editor creates a page as sub-page of Toy (main), only sub-Toy template will be available.

Comment: Yes, [Set the Insert Options](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/03/All-About-Insert-Options-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx) so only `sub-Toy` is available as an option on `Toy`. Remember as a regular user (with the correct roles/permissions) the `Insert from Templates` should be available.

Comment: My comment should have read "should **NOT** be available". Crucial point :)